# how to update OneToOneField / ForeignKey using ViewSet? Django

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, model

I am currently using restful and serializers to create and update my user.
Somehow I am not able to update some of the fields if the field has to do with OneToOneField / ForeignKey.

in my models.py, my Student is actually connected to the django build in user model which includes the user's email and connected to the school model which has the name of the school

```
class Student(Model):
    user = OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=CASCADE)

    date_of_birth = DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    student_name = CharField(max_length=256)
    school = ForeignKey(School,
                        on_delete=CASCADE,
                        related_name="%(class)ss",
                        related_query_name="%(class)s",
                        blank=True,
                        null=True)
```

in serializer.py I have

```
class StudentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user_email = SerializerMethodField()
    school_name = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = (
            'user_email', 'student_name', 'phone', 'school_name')

    def get_user_email(self, obj):
        return obj.user.email

    def get_school_name(self, obj):
        return obj.school.school_name

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Student.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.user.email = validated_data.get('user_email', instance.user.email)
        instance.student_name = validated_data.get('student_name', instance.student_name)
        instance.phone = validated_data.get('phone', instance.phone)
        instance.school.school_name = validated_data.get('school_name', instance.school.school_name)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

in my view.py update function

```
class UserViewSet(ViewSet):
    queryset = Student.objects.all()

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        student = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = StudentSerializer(student, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'status': True})
        return Response({'status': False, 'message': serializer.errors})
```

I am able to use the API view to pass in json and update the `student_name` and `phone` but as for the other two, `user_email` and `school_name` I am not able to update it.  I don't get any error output when I submit the json though.

I realized the two fields that I am not able to update are because they OneToOneField / ForeignKey.

Can someone please give me a hand what I am missing here or what I can do to check?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `instance..school.school_name`, you just typo in this stackoverflow or in your script?

Comment: @SancaKembang in stackoverflow :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested seriailzer / model / presentation actually helped me get the work done and pretty helpful.

An example is also provided here.
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-update-methods-for-nested-representations

the above is continued from 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-create-methods-for-nested-representations which contained how the nested serializer is being setup in the class and meta's fields

Answer (score 3):

I think your serializer isn't completed... the field of `user` and `school` is instance model, you need specific field in your serializer to implement the instance model, eg: with [`source='...'`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) argument.

and example:

```
class VoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # by `username`
    user = serializers.CharField(
        source='user.username',
        read_only=True
    )
    # by `pk/id`
    candidate = serializers.IntegerField(
        source='candidate.pk',
        read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Vote
        fields = ('user', 'candidate', 'score')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Vote.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

and in your case, perhaps is like this;

```
class StudentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    # by `pk/id` from the user
    user = serializers.IntegerField(
        source='user.pk',
        read_only=True
    )
    school = serializers.IntegerField(
        source='school.pk',
        read_only=True
    )
```

Comment: I just tried this though and of course I need to use `user_email` with `EmailField` instead of what you should but still no luck though.  I don't get any errors trying to update it

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using **SerializerMethodField** which is readonly field ([docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)) for **user_email** and **school_name** so they won't be available in the **validated_data**.

Have you check the data you are receiving in **validated_data**

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    print('++'*22, validated_data)
    return instance
```